# Thread management pattern or package in Java SE?

Tags: java, multithreading, frameworks

I'm faced with a very slow data import console app and I'm trying to speed it up by multithreading it.

Is there an example pattern for starting and managing X number of worker threads in a console app?   Ideally I was hoping that there would be something like:

```
ThreadManager tm = new ThreadManager(maxthreads=10);
while (moreWork = true) {
    tm.addThread(new Thread(new MyClass));
}
```

The ThreadManager would add threads until the max was reached and then wait patiently until a slot became available for a new thread.

Anything like that out there?   I can't be the first one that's faced this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@jeshurun's answer is correct but for posterity, I thought I'd add some more information.  If you utilize the great `ExecutorService` code then your code would turn into:

```
ExecutorService threadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
while (moreWork) {
    threadPool.submit(new MyClass);
}
// stop pool after you've submitted the last job, submitted jobs will still run
threadPool.shutdown();
// you can wait for the last job to finish if you'd like
threadPool.awaitTermination(Long.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

Your `MyClass` should either implement `Runnable` or `Callable`.  If it is a `Runnable` then the thread pool will execute the `MyClass.run()` method when it has an available thread.  Same with `Callable` except that the `Future<?>` returned by the `submit()` method can be used to get the value returned by your `MyClass.call()` method.  You can also get any exceptions that were thrown by `call()`.  Here's a [decent tutorial](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-util-concurrent/executorservice.html).

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Java 5 or above, why don't you use the `ExecutorService` interface from the java.util.concurrent framework, and its implementation `ThreadPoolExecutor` for managing a fixed number of threads? Normally you would use one of the static methods in the `Executors` class to obtain an instance of a ThreadPool with a fixed size, and submit as many threads as you want to it for execution.

The documentation for `ThreadPoolExecutor` and all its friends in the java.util.concurrent package is available [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html).

Comment: This information should be in a big red box on all the "How to use Threads in Java" tutorials on the net.   Trying to multithread an app without this information is like trying to drive a car engine without the car - plenty of power, no way to use it. Thank you very much!